# HTML5 AppCache in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview

I'd like to make use of appcache in my native application on the iPhone. Though Mobile Safari supports appcache it seems that the UIWebView that you can embed in an application does not.

I know with a bit of work, I could simulate some sort of appcache like functionality in my application, but this isn't good enough - I'd like access to the same appcache that Mobile Safari uses.

I'd be willing to use some of the Private Frameworks in the iPhone SDK, as getting this working is a much higher priority than being able to submit to the app store.

Thanks!

Comment: but making use of private framework will make your app to be rejected.

Comment: Same question with more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540240/html5-cache-manifest-in-a-uiwebview

Comment: maybe you could help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287044/my-html5-application-cache-manifest-is-caching-everything