# Does phonegap support offline storage cache manifest?

Tags: iphone, android, ios, cordova

Does phonegap supports offline storage cache manifest mentioned in this article http://blogs.missouristate.edu/web/2010/05/12/google-maps-api-v3-developing-for-mobile-devices/?

I want to use cache manifest to cache google maps scripts and tiles to boost performance of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. I got this is straight from an Apple employee dev (at WWDC) from a Safari session (UIWebView no, Mobile Safari yes)

Comment: Hmm. That is really bad news. Cache manifest is the only thing that will allow to cache google api and map tiles =\ Using cache manifest was also recomended by Google team in their blog for mobile devises.

Comment: Did you see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540240/html5-cache-manifest-in-a-uiwebview It appears possible on iOS 4+, provided you do the manifest properly.

Comment: looks like the apple employee dev got it wrong. adding headers for manifest file worked on iOS 4.3 http://stackoverflow.com/a/3586498/522050

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are some problems with UIWebView's and cache manifest files.

[Html5 cache manifest in a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540240/html5-cache-manifest-in-a-uiwebview/3586498#3586498)

There are answers to similar questions on the PhoneGap google groups mailing list however that suggest it cannot be done in PhoneGap at all.

Note: I also saw someone answer your question on the google groups mailing list, simply suggesting that in the example you gave they were caching files that you could just include in your PhoneGap application. While this would work if the files were once off, if they ever needed updating this would be no good, not so much "cached" as "static".

Perhaps if this was the case you could use the PhoneGap File api to get updated versions of the files and store them locally (overwriting the old)?