# Using HTML5 cache manifest with Phonegap on iOS

Tags: ios, html, cordova, browser-cache

I've been trying for a while to make my HTML5 cache manifest work with phonegap on iOS devices, but I can't get it working (it does work with the pure web version of the app though).

Has anyone have used it successfully?
(I've only founded two people saying that it has worked ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586498/1812349), [2](http://artem.savelev.com/2012/08/phonegap-cordova-appcache/)), but I'm searching for more feedback)

Comment: Did you find any answer to this? I seem to be having the same problem. Its working in Chrome, but not in cordova on iOS...

Comment: the version of phonedgap that I was using wasn't compatible with html5 cache, it seem that it is now compatible, bug i dit not have the time to try it

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at this article

http://tmkmobile.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/html5-offline-solution/

I haven't worked in iOS myself but by the sound of it, as long you have correctly setup your cache spec, it should just work on iOS. Only Android needs a little extra work.