# Does the UIWebView can use the HTML5 AppCache

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, manifest, html5-appcache

I have an `UIWebView` which loads sites that made in `HTML5`. A `manifest` is implemented too. So my question is can I use the `HTML5 AppCache` or do I have to develope it by myself?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099820/5629933) tells me that the `UIWebView` can't use the `HTML5 AppCache`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but you're limited to only about 5MB of cache storage.  You build a .manifest file which tells UIWebView which files to cache. You should read your indicated post for further information.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Did I have to activate something? If I turn of WiFi the site has to load but the only thing I got is a white site. `Manifest` exists, website is developed in `HTML5` so offline should work. I tried so many things, googled and nothing worked. It's annoying. I thought I will load the source code of the website, saving them into a specific directory and call the file like the URL but it doesn't seems to be the best way