# "Legality" of using web resources and appcache inside UIWebView/Phonegap

Tags: iphone, html, caching, uiwebview, app-store

We are trying to develop a hybrid app that can update itself by using css/javascript/html from the internet, instead of storing them in the phonegap project.

Like so 
[Html5 cache manifest in a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540240/html5-cache-manifest-in-a-uiwebview)

[HTML5 AppCache in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247264/html5-appcache-in-uiwebview)

It now does work fine on iOS 5 and 5.1

In fact, inside phonegap index.html we do  or location.href redirect to the web site. The web site has offline manifest, which allows the phonegap app to start and work the second time in an offline mode (after all resources were cached the first time). And changes to manifest do update the app correctly. I have tried terminating the app in the phone, and restarting it while the web site is down - it still works.

There are solutions that allow self update - for example the phonegap-based Worklight. So silent self-update doesn't seem to be an issue anymore.

So the question is, did anybody submit similar an app to appstore? There's potentially no code at all in the app, all it does is goes to the web site.

Answer (score 5):

Apple appears to allow apps to download data updates and Javascript/HTML for use in UIWebViews.  They even presented a WWDC session on data driven apps a couple years back.

But note this item in Apple's app review guidelines:

2.12 Apps that are ... simply web sites bundled as apps ... may be rejected.

The only way to know for sure if your app is acceptable is to submit it to Apple for review, as "similar" apps do not appear to set any precedent for any future approvals.